# Почему слово "смеситель" часто неправильно произносят и/или пишут как "сместитель"?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия, существительные

В последнее время часто это слово слышу от одного человека, но в основном, в неправильном произношении. У меня человек произносит это слово как "сместитель". Я это слово стал часто слышать в связи с ремонтом в ванной комнате, который в моей квартире недавно сделали.

Comment: Один человек неправильно говорит, и это уже значит, что часто произносят? Пусть даже два.

Comment: Но это не значит, что только один мой человек так произносит слово "смеситель". Другие тоже неправильно произносят это слово.

Comment: Сколько их всего?

Comment: А вы не пробовали у них спросить, почему они так говорят? По-моему, был бы лучший ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: *У меня человек произносит это слово*, — это как понять?

Comment: я это слышал только от своего близкого человека

Comment: Ну так это не значит, что и другие так говорят. Надо у него спросить, почему он так говорит. И в других случаях тоже так поступать. Нам-то откуда знать, почему они неправильно говорят? Можно лишь догадки строить.